# Every element of $R:=K[x][\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ can be written as $[f+\epsilon g]$

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and a ring $R:=K[x][\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ where we use the notation $[h]:=h+(\epsilon^2)$ for $h\in K[x][\epsilon]=K[x,\epsilon]$

Show that every element of $R$ can be written as $[f+\epsilon g]$ with unique $f,g\in K[x]$

My problems with this question start with the fact that I don't know what is meant with this notation. I know that $K[x]$ would be the ring of polynomials over the field $K$ but what is $R:=K[x][\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ ? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write $A$ for the ring $K[x]$.

Then $A[\epsilon]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $A$, i.e. $$A[\epsilon] = \{ a_0 + a_1 \epsilon + \dots + a_d\epsilon^d: a_i \in A \}.$$

And $(\epsilon^2)$ is the ideal of $A[\epsilon]$ generated by the element $\epsilon^2$, i.e. $$(\epsilon^2) = \{\epsilon^2 f: f \in A[\epsilon]\}.$$

Finally, $R = A[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ is the quotient ring of $A[\epsilon]$ by the ideal $(\epsilon^2)$.

As you are only asking for the meaning of the notation, I will stop here and leave it to you to solve the problem.